# Linear and nonlinear functions in the context of differential equations and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

When people describe linear or nonlinear functions in the context of differential equations, are they actually referring to affine functions, rather than linear functions? In my mind, linear functions and are those that (1) contain the origin/$0$ vector, (2) are closed under addition, and (3) are closed under multiplication. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear differential equations are linear operators acting on function spaces.  For example, consider the following ODE:

$$y''+a(x)y' + b(x)y = c(x).$$

This is equivalent to

$D(y) = c$

where $D$ is the **linear** differential operator $D = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+a(x)\frac{d}{dx}+b(x)$. To be clear, $D$ inputs a function and outputs another function:

$D(f) = f''+a(x)f'+b(x)f$.

Indeed you can check that $D$ is linear,

$D(\alpha f + \beta g)  = \alpha D(f) +\beta D(g)$,

and in particular $D(0) =0$.

Comment: I can't tell if/where your post addresses my question.

Comment: Linear differential equations are called linear because the differential operator is a linear operator.  Details and an example are above; maybe I am misunderstanding your question?  As another comparison the matrix equation Ax = y is linear because the matrix (operator) A is linear.  In differential equations the differential operator D plays exactly the same role as A.  Does that clarify?

Comment: Does that mean that 'linear function' in this context refers to affine functions, as opposed to the 'linear function' of linear algebra?

Comment: No, precisely not; the differential operator D satisfies D(0) = 0 so it is linear just as in matrix equations.